# Flutter, cupertinotabview keyboard is not showing up

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Am I doing something wrong with this super simple app?

I have CupertinoTabView with two tabs. The first one shows a Page which holds a textfield. Problem is when I tap on the textfield, the keyboard is showing for a fraction of a second and then hides again.

[Link to issue on flutter github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28457)

Comment: I tried using the code you shared and I am not getting any error. Are you using an emulator? Did you un-check the connect hardware keyboard?

Comment: I could reproduce.

Comment: I have tried both with ios-simulator as well as my actual android device. Getting the same error on both.

Comment: Glad to hear it is not on my end :)